# What to say when someone says, "What's up?"?

Tags: word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an appropriate response to “what’s up” greeting?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2471/what-is-an-appropriate-response-to-whats-up-greeting)
>   [Response to “What's up?” in various conversations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19966/response-to-whats-up-in-various-conversations)

I recently came back from US, Over there I noticed people say What's Up all the time, and even in movies and shows that I watch. But when someone said that to me I was like "What I am supposed to say" I am just sitting here doing nothing, so I always said hesitantly "Nothing". I am one of people who are always doing nothing, so It was really a pain. So what is it that is supposed to be said when someone says?