# How to reply to the question, "What's up?"

Tags: greetings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an appropriate response to “what's up” greeting?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2471/what-is-an-appropriate-response-to-whats-up-greeting)

If someone asks me "What's up, man?," how should I reply? What does it mean?